# Where the registerModule code should live when using jackson

Tags: java, jackson

This is my test code.

```
DynaBean bean1 = new LazyDynaBean();
bean1.set("p1", 1);
bean1.set("p2", 2);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    LOGGER.error(mapper.writeValueAsString(bean1));
} catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
    LOGGER.catching(ex);
}
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("SimpleModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, "com.bolan", "oa"));
simpleModule.addSerializer(DynaBean.class, new DynaBeanSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

DynaBean bean2 = new LazyDynaBean();
bean2.set("p1", 1);
bean2.set("p2", 2);
try {
    LOGGER.error(mapper.writeValueAsString(bean2));
} catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
    LOGGER.catching(ex);
}
```

This is the source of DynaBeanSerializer:

```
public class DynaBeanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DynaBean> {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(DynaBeanSerializer.class);

    @Override
    public void serialize(DynaBean value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        LOGGER.info("serializing the byna bean!");
        gen.writeStartObject();
        DynaProperty[] dynaProperties = value.getDynaClass().getDynaProperties();
        for (DynaProperty dynaProperty : dynaProperties) {
            try {
                gen.writeObjectField(dynaProperty.getName(), PropertyUtils.getProperty(value, dynaProperty.getName()));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                LOGGER.error(ex);
            }
        }
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<DynaBean> handledType() {
        LOGGER.info("get JsonSerializer type!");
        return DynaBean.class;
    }

}
```

And the output is:

```
10:18:09.794 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR com.bolan.test.javafx.test.FXMLController - {"dynaClass":{"dynaBeanClass":"org.apache.commons.beanutils.LazyDynaBean","name":"org.apache.commons.beanutils.LazyDynaClass","restricted":false,"returnNull":false,"dynaProperties":[{"name":"p1","type":"java.lang.Integer","contentType":null,"indexed":false,"mapped":false},{"name":"p2","type":"java.lang.Integer","contentType":null,"indexed":false,"mapped":false}]},"map":{"p2":2,"p1":1}}
10:18:09.797 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR com.bolan.test.javafx.test.FXMLController - {"dynaClass":{"dynaBeanClass":"org.apache.commons.beanutils.LazyDynaBean","name":"org.apache.commons.beanutils.LazyDynaClass","restricted":false,"returnNull":false,"dynaProperties":[{"name":"p1","type":"java.lang.Integer","contentType":null,"indexed":false,"mapped":false},{"name":"p2","type":"java.lang.Integer","contentType":null,"indexed":false,"mapped":false}]},"map":{"p2":2,"p1":1}}
```

However I wish the output like this:

```
10:21:03.933 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR com.bolan.test.javafx.test.FXMLController - {"p1":1,"p2":2}
```

What's more, if I edit the test code as following:

```
DynaBean bean1 = new LazyDynaBean();
bean1.set("p1", 1);
bean1.set("p2", 2);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("SimpleModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, "com.bolan", "oa"));
simpleModule.addSerializer(DynaBean.class, new DynaBeanSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

DynaBean bean2 = new LazyDynaBean();
bean2.set("p1", 1);
bean2.set("p2", 2);
try {
    LOGGER.error(mapper.writeValueAsString(bean2));
} catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
    LOGGER.catching(ex);
}
```

The output is that I wish~ It's very very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST register all modules you are going to use before using `ObjectMapper` for the first time. Registration after usage may or may not have effect; but specifically adding custom (de)serializers for types you have already serialized/deserialized will NOT have effect due to caching of serializers and deserializers.

Comment: In fact, I am using resteasy. I want to customize the serializer of some class. But it didn't work. When I debug, I found my custom objectmapper is created by reateasy, but the custom serializer not work. I will show my code in the following reply.

Comment: I wonder if there is any proxy-class creation RestEasy does. Your code looks correct to me, nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my resteasy code to expore the objectmapper to the framework:

```
@Provider
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class CustomJsonProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CustomJsonProvider.class);
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public CustomJsonProvider() {
        LOGGER.info("Register provider CustomJsonProvider for resteasy");
        this.mapper = new CustomObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        LOGGER.info("Get provider CustomJsonProvider for resteasy");
        return mapper;
    }

}
```

"CustomJsonProvider()" is called once during the development time, and "getContext" is called everytime my object is serialized. However, my custom serializers was not used by the resteasy.

This is the source code of CustomObjectMapper:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CustomObjectMapper.class);

    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("SimpleModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, "com.bolan", "oa"));
        simpleModule.addSerializer(DynaBean.class, new DynaBeanSerializer());
        registerModule(simpleModule);
    }
```

And the source code of DynaBeanSerializer is showed in the question.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Test</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.jndi.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>java:app/service/LocatingResourceBean,java:app/service/SimpleResourceBean</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>com.bolan.rest.provider.CustomJsonProvider,com.bolan.rest.provider.CustomJsonBodyWriter</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
<!--    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>oa</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>oa</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```